# Can you recommend a way to generate access token?

Tags: oauth, token, access-token

My team are coding a web app, which include a server and a client, I think it's obviously not advisable to send user's `uid` and `password` to server every request from client.

I am looking for a good choice to deal with this, maybe something like `Oauth`, is there any efficient approach?

For example, a user with username `lyj` and password `123456` request login from my client app, the server should check if it is permissible, after login success, the client can send more request to get other resource from server.
My problem is that, except userid and password, is there a way between server and client to make sure who is this guy, is there any suggest to transmit a `access token` between server and client?

Comment: More information on the backend is required.

Answer (score 2):

Without much information on your platform and technologies I can only attempt a generic answer. There are several ways in which you can generate a token depending on how you want to use it. [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a well established algorithm and you can use it to generate a oth token using something like username and email etc. Remember that you cannot decrypt MD5 string. So to do any kind of verification you will have to recreate the string using original parameters and then perform a check. If you want a hash that you can reverse you can look at something like base-64.

Both MD6 and base-64 are easily available as libraries in any back end you may be using.

* UPDATE

Looking at your comments that you are working with a stateless client, here is a possible approach to using tokens.

1. Client performs login for first time. (preferably HTTPS)
2. Server performs validation and generates a token using MD5(or any other of your choice) using (username+email+ip_address+time_stamp) and sends it back to client
3. Server creates a new session for this client in the table in the database using userID , ip_address and, time_stamp
4. Client passes this token back for any future requests.
5. When client passes the token , server retrieves the session from the database and generates the MD5 hash and compares it with the token client sent. If its the same you are good.
6. You can also use the time-stamp value a validity window for your tokens so they are not valid forever. Also its impossible to recreate this token unless someone can create the same MD5 hash at the same time down to milliseconds

Comment: Is there any probability for someone else to get this token and then imitation to server?

Comment: if they use exactly same combination of original string to generate a MD5 then yes they can generate the same token. But that is unlikely. as its usually impossible to guess from looking at a MD5 string what the original string was. If you really want to make it completely secured, you might want to add timestamp string to the MD5 hash too and store this time stamp so you can recreate the string later. So you know when a token is coming in that it was generated by you!

Comment: According to your answer, both client and server should store a secret token to generate md5 token, and this secret needn't transmit accompany with client's request, in order to avoid capturing by others?

Comment: not sure what you mean. can you say that in a little more details please?

Comment: Is there any possibility for others to get http package and get the access token, then imitation to server?

Answer (score 0):

Modern web application containers have embedded the session tracking functionality. Of course there is always the choice of cookies. Its up to you what to implement...

Comment: Becase of the stateless of http, I don't want to transmit username and password every time when client request comes.